# Shortening URLs using .htaccess / mod_rewrite?

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter

How would I go about shortening down my URLs? At present my URLs are like `http://www.server.com/username/aa/index.php/site/products` and I'd prefer the `index.php` part not to be there if possible.

Comment: This is addressed in the CodeIgniter user guide: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/urls.html

Comment: I tried doing what was suggested there but I still have to use `index.php` in the URL to access the relevant views or it doesn't work.

Comment: In the config.php, $config['base_url'] should be '' and not index.php

Comment: Yeah I already changed that (forgot to mention) and I still have to have the index.php in the URL or I get not found errors.

Answer (score 1):

In general you can a regular expression to fish out the stuff you want to keep and then concatenate it into a replacement. In the snippet bellow ^(.*) (1 or more of any character from the beginning till we hit 'index.php') becomes $1 and eveything after index.php $2

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/index\.php/(.*)$ $1/$2[L]
```

As far as codeingniter and other frameworks go, this should not be necessary at all, you should have something like this in the public directory of your project:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d 
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

This willfetch anything going to this directory and redirect to index.php unless a file or directory or link with the explicit name exists